# React native refreshControl ScrollView bottom-sheet ios

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, bottom-sheet, pull-to-refresh

I am using the following component [bottom-sheet](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet), where I am implementing the `pull-to-refresh`, on `android` it works perfectly on `ios` it is not working.

I tried to follow various guides, but I could not figure out what the problem is that on `ios` it is not working.

Can anyone help me out?

Android ok:

[image]

Link: [snack](https://snack.expo.io/7YFzq4J1e)

```
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useMemo, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  RefreshControl,
  ToastAndroid,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetScrollView } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const App = () => {
  // hooks
  const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);
  const [listData, setListData] = React.useState([]);

  const onRefresh = React.useCallback(async () => {
    console.log('Refresh');
    setRefreshing(true);
    try {
      const n = getRandomInt(10, 30);
      console.log(n);
      let response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=' + n);
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      setListData(responseJson.results);
      setRefreshing(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }, [refreshing]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onRefresh();
  }, []);

  // variables
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%', '90%'], []);

  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChange = useCallback((index) => {
    console.log('handleSheetChange', index);
  }, []);
  const handleSnapPress = useCallback((index) => {
    sheetRef.current?.snapTo(index);
  }, []);
  const handleClosePress = useCallback(() => {
    sheetRef.current?.close();
  }, []);

  // render
  const renderItem = useCallback(
    (item) => (
      <View key={item.login.uuid} style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <Text>{item.email}</Text>
      </View>
    ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BottomSheet
        ref={sheetRef}
        index={2}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onChange={handleSheetChange}
        enableContentPanningGesture={false}
        enableHandlePanningGesture={false}>
        <BottomSheetScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            //paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 64,
          }}
          contentInset={{ top: 64 }}
          contentOffset={{ x: 0, y: -64 }}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={refreshing}
              onRefresh={onRefresh}
              progressViewOffset={64}
              colors={['#000']}
              tintColor={'#000'}
            />
          }>
          {listData.map(renderItem)}
        </BottomSheetScrollView>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 200,
  },
  contentContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  itemContainer: {
    padding: 6,
    margin: 6,
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: It works with ScrollView, imported from 'react-native'.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze: I don't understand what the problem could be: https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/blob/master/src/components/scrollView/ScrollView.tsx

Comment: I think `bounces={false}` block refreshControl.